# get_object_vars returning different results depending on PHP version

Tags: php

This isn't really a surprise that function implementations change sometimes from version to version, but not like this... Look:

```
$array = ["abc","def"];
$object = new stdclass();
foreach($array as $index => $value) {
    $object->$index = $value;
}
var_dump(get_object_vars($object));
```

For 5.6.x and then e.g. 7.0.17 and 7.1.3 we get:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(3) "abc" 
[1]=> string(3) "def" 
}
```

But for 7.0.0 and 7.0.16 and 7.1.0 we get:

```
array(2) { 
["0"]=> string(3) "abc" 
["1"]=> string(3) "def" 
}
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/jog4A

See? The keys are integers OR strings, depending on version.

Why? What is the reasoning behind those changes? And why isn't this documented anywhere? Or... is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look more closely at the versions on that 3v4.org output, it was broken in 7.0.0 up to and including 7.0.16, and 7.1.0 up to and including 7.1.2. So this was a bug introduced in 7.0, and fixed on both active releases in time for 7.0.17 and 7.1.3 (both release March 16 2017).

Looking at [the PHP changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.3) we can see a relevant looking entry:

> Fixed bug #73998 (array_key_exists fails on arrays created by get_object_vars).

This leads us to [the bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73998), and from there to [commit dd9cf23457e21d2bda29dc92d437b9dbd14027b2 in th git repo](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=dd9cf23457e21d2bda29dc92d437b9dbd14027b2):

> BUG #73998: Numeric properties are not accessible from get_object_vars

The fix involves adding a check for if there are numeric keys present, and skipping a block labelled "fast_copy" if there are.

So this was an undesired side-effect of a performance optimisation made during the development of PHP 7, and has now been fixed in all supported releases.

Interestingly, Andrea commented on the bug report that it is closely related to [an RFC to change the behaviour of object-to-array casts](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/convert_numeric_keys_in_object_array_casts) which describes the general problem:

> Because arrays and objects have different restrictions versus the underlying HashTable type on what kinds of keys they can have, the Zend Engine must enforce their restrictions at a layer above HashTables, in the code implementing arrays and objects themselves. This means that if that code is bypassed and the underlying HashTables are modified directly, arrays and objects can exist with an invalid internal state.

And the specific case addressed by the RFC:

> For example, $arr = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]; $obj = (object)$arr; produces an object with inaccessible properties named  , 1 and 2, while $obj = new stdClass; $obj->{'0'} = 1; $obj->{'1'} = 2; $obj->{'2'} = 3; produces an array with the inaccessible keys "0", "1" and "2". The same issue also occurs when using get_object_vars().

The RFC is implemented in 7.2.0, as it changes documented behaviour, but the behaviour of `get_object_vars()` was actually an inadvertent change in 7.0, so was implemented as a bug fix.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a bug, because variables must start with letter.

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

So when you are trying to set variables `$object->$index = $value;` it must throw an error (you cant set the variable like this `$1 = 'foo';` or `$obj->1 = 'foo';`).

```
array(2) { 
["0"]=> string(3) "abc" 
["1"]=> string(3) "def" 
}
```

Is a right result, because `get_object_vars` returns associative array.

> Return Values ¶
>
> Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static
>   properties for the specified object in scope. If a property has not
>   been assigned a value, it will be returned with a NULL value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: so do you mean its bug in php7 ?
according to get-object-vars link it should return key as string in php 5.6 also. Can you clarify more @Neodan

Comment: @Neodan Thanks, but... you actually can create a property starting with a number: $x->{'1'} = 23; 

https://3v4l.org/Je7Jl

Plus, I second Naincy's question:)

Comment: Associative array have named keys it means that key must be a string. But I think that the problem is not in the key data type, but that you can create a variables which breaks the rules of variable naming.

Comment: Variable names and property names are not the same thing, so that is not the relevant part of the manual to look at.

Comment: @IMSoP but you can't declare a property like this `public $1 = 'foo';` :)

Comment: Sure, but you can create one, as shown in the OP's code. It's not a good idea, but it's not actually prohibited. There are other properties you can access but not declare too, e.g. `$foo->{'some-hypenated-phrase'}`. This is used in things like JSON or XML parsers to avoid having to mangle the names in the source data.